# Adjusting vertical alignment of sidenotes in Eledmac

Tags: vertical-alignment, eledmac, sidenotes

I am using Eledmac to typeset a lengthy document which contains sidenotes.
The body of the document is to be double-spaced, but I want the sidenotes to be single-spaced and in a smaller point size (`\scriptsize`). I am using the `\rightnoteupfalse` command which should sets the beginning of the sidenote opposite the line in which the sidenote command (`\ledrightnote`) is inserted.
Throughout the document, however, the sidenote ends up exactly one line BELOW where it should be. Yes, I am a neophyte to LaTeX. Could someone tell me what has caused this problem or how I might adjust the vertical alignment of sidenotes globally in order to compensate for it? Here is a short file illustrating the problem:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\rightnoteupfalse

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent,            a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.
Now we are engaged in a great \emph{civil war} \ledrightnote{\singlespacing{{\scriptsize I would like this sidenote to begin on the same line as civil war}}} testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.

\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: I look for your problem. But as neophyte to LaTeX, you should use reledmac and not eledmac. Eledmac won't be maintened any more.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that changing line spacing insert vertical space (\vskip) for correction, which in most case is required, but in this specific case as not desirable space. The solution is to "compensate" this space.

For example

```
\ledrightnote{\singlespacing
\vskip-2.1666\baselineskip\scriptsize
I would like this sidenote to begin on the same line as civil war}
```

(The exacte value is depending of you base font, I am not a specialist of vertical spacing, but in my test it was probant).

As you will use this structure many time, create your own command:

```
\newcommand{\mysidenote}[1]{\ledrightnote{\singlespacing
\vskip-2.166\baselineskip\scriptsize#1}}
```

To use as

```
\mysidenote{I would like this sidenote to begin on the same line as civil war}
```

Ps 1) you should delete the space before \ledrightnote, because it provokes double spacing.
Ps 2) As I have said, you should use reledmac instead of eledmac.

Comment: Dear Maïeul, the procedures you recommended work perfectly! Thank you for showing them to me!

Comment: you'r welcome, Don't forget to validate the answer and vote up.